# Issue with flash plugin in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash-player

I'm facing some problems with Google Chrome 45 and its flash plugin.

It seems like there is something blocking the execution of flash banners. It's shown a static image with a "play" button overlaying it. When I click this button, nothing happens.

This is only reproduceable in my client's PCs (3 of them), but I was not able to reproduce it in mine.

I've checked for installed extensions that could be blocking and turned out he does not have any extension installed.

Here is a print of the problem:
[image: Print]

Comment: Isn't this a feature of Chrome now? Pretty sure NOBODY likes Flash these days.

Answer (score 1):

Google have disabled autoplay Flash Ads in Google Chrome.

> In June, we announced (https://goo.gl/TF7dmD) that Chrome will begin pausing many Flash ads by default to improve performance for users. This change is scheduled to start rolling out on September 1, 2015.

Source: https://plus.google.com/+GoogleAds/posts/2PmwKinJ7nj